# Adding pivot columns in powerBI desktop using columns from different tables

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Using PowerBI Desktop, I imported the following tables:

```
Table name: inventory
columns:

  item_code
  warehouse_code
  quantity

Table name: warehouses
columns:

  item_code
  location
```

The possibilities for location are:

```
headquarters
east_coast
```

What I would like to, is to have pivot columns, added to the inventory table, using the names in the location column of the warehouses table, and values from the quantity column of the inventory table.

So. following the pivot, the inventory table in the model, would have the following columns:

```
  item_code
  warehouse_code
  quantity
  headqurters
  east_coast
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Can you show us the output structure that you would like to see?

Comment: It's described in my question, but I just added a couple of more lines.